# Callback gets activated without selection in Plotly Dash

Tags: python, callback, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I am creating a dashboard with Plotly Dash but I am having some trouble using the callbacks.

Firstly I don't understand completely the difference between using 'value', 'options' or 'children' and how many more options are there for the input/output calls. Ex:

```
@app.callback(
    Output("output", "children"),
    Input("num_exp", "value"),
)
```

Secondly, although the dropdown works fine after I select an option, at the beginning when running the code it already gives this error returning the 'None' selection. I don't get why this happens since I thought the callback was just activated when actually selecting something in the dropdown.

[image: error]
[image: keyerror]

Any help would be useful :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, your callback as shown in the error message needs to have an `Input`. Right now, it doesn't, so the code thinks the function parameter `dd_properties` is `None`. You then try to use that to index into a list or something, and it breaks. That's your `KeyError`.

The difference between the properties (props) you use (ex. `value`, `children`, etc.) is what part of the component you are targeting. So, you could have something like this

```py
html.Div(
    id='my-id',
    children='This is my favorite color',
    style=dict(color='blue'),  # no, yellooooooooow
)
```

You can have a callback output its value to the `children` prop by setting up your callback with `Output('my-id', 'children')`, or you can have it output to the `style` property with `Output('my-id', 'style')`. The same works for `Input`, and what prop triggers the callback. For a dropdown, if the `value` prop from the component is used (`Input('my-dropdown', 'value')`), then the callback will run when someone makes a selection in the dropdown menu. However, if the `options` prop is used, then the callback runs when the list of options in the dropdown changes, perhaps as a result of another callback which output to the `options` prop (resulting in chained callbacks).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response! However, I did have an input in the call back. This is the code: `@app.callback(
    # enabling 1D analysis if one of the options selected
    Output("dd_1danalysis", "options" ),
    # selection in property dropdown
    Input("dd_properties", "value")
)
def get_1doptions(dd_properties):
    return [{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in all_options_properties[dd_properties]]` Thus, I still don't get why is getting activated without any selection.

Comment: This is one of the dropdowns contained in the app layout:                                                                                `html.Label([
            html.I("Property: "),
            dcc.Dropdown(
                id = 'dd_properties', 
                clearable = False,
                placeholder = 'Select property',
                options=[
                    {'label': i, 'value': i}
                    for i in properties
                ], className = 'dcc_compon')
        ]),`

Comment: Ok. In that case, the problem is that your dropdown does have a `value` prop defined. In that case, Dash sets it as `None`, which is what's getting through to your callback. Just set a default `value` and you should be good.

Answer (score 1):

The way I solved this was by using the n_clicks variable within my submit button and set it to 0 (`n_clicks=0`)
inside the actual callback funtion i added an if statement to return an empty figure:

```
if n_clicks == 0:
        return empty_figure
```

and this was my code for the empty figure:

```
empty_figure = go.Figure()
empty_figure.update_layout(plot_bgcolor=app_color["graph_bg"], paper_bgcolor=app_color["graph_bg"],
                          yaxis = dict(showgrid=False, zeroline=False, tickfont = dict(color = app_color["graph_line"])),
                          xaxis = dict(showgrid=False, zeroline=False, tickfont = dict(color = app_color["graph_line"])))
```

then, on each graph, the input was set to

```
Input('submit-button', 'n_clicks')
```

and I passed the actual input value as a State:

```
State('input-on-submit', 'value')
```

hope this helps, good luck!